# cURL error 60 on Php 7.1.8 - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I got this message in Laravel log:

```
RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187:
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I use Laravel 5.3, PHP 7.1.8, xampp, Windows 8.1

I tried with wamp64 & wamp32 also with the same results.

What can I do, any suggestions?

Is not in the answer of

[PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

I am using php 7 and is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: No luck in that. I tested in xampp and wamp64. Not working!